# Finding the largest domain on which a series expansion converges

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I need to find the largest domain on which the series expansion of $f(z) = -\frac{1}{z-\pi/2}-\frac{1}{z+\pi/2} = 2*\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{2}{\pi})^{2*k}z^{2k-1}$. I tried using the ratio test, but I got as an answer that it converges for $z \leq \pi/2$ but the answers in my book say the largest domain on which it converges is $z \geq \pi/2$. Could anyone explain how the book gets this result? Thanks!

Comment: It should be $|z|\lt \pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take the original expression:

$$f(z)=\frac1{\frac\pi2-z}-\frac1{\frac\pi2+z}=\frac2\pi\left(\frac1{1-\frac{2z}\pi}-\frac1{1+\frac{2z}\pi}\right)=\frac2\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac2\pi\right)^n\left(z^n-(-1)^nz^n\right)$$

the last equality being true for $\;\left|\frac{2z}\pi\right|<1\iff|z|<\frac\pi2\;$ .

If you want to simplify a little more observe that

$$z^n-(-1)^nz^n=z^n+(-1)^{n+1}z^n=\begin{cases}0\,,\;&n\;\text{even}\\{}\\2z^n\, \;&n\;\text{odd}\end{cases}$$

so that we can write a little more compactly

$$f(z)=\frac4\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac2\pi\right)^{2n+1}z^{2n+1}$$

Comment: So the largest domain for which the expression converges would be $|z| < \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @urpi My expression? Yes, it is. I just cannot figure out how you reached the expression in your question

Comment: Well, from the expression $\frac{2}{\pi}(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2z}{\pi}}-\frac{1}{1+\frac{2z}{\pi}}))$ I expanded the terms inside the parenthesis using geometric series, where some of my terms cancelled and that's how I got my expression.

Comment: @urpi Thank you. That's what I did yet I don't quite follow how you got the exponent $\;2k-1\;$ for $\;z\;$ in your series...

Comment: So, when I expand inside the parenthesis, I get $\frac{2}{\pi}((1+\frac{2z}{\pi}+(\frac{2z}{\pi})^2+...)-(1-\frac{2z}{\pi}+( \frac{2z}{\pi} )^2-(\frac{2z}{\pi})^3+...))$, where the even terms start cancelling.

Comment: @urpi Of course, you're right! I forgot the minus sign between the terms in the series, so it is the even ones that vanish. Thank you, I shall edit now. Nevertheless, the convergence radius remains, of course